# Angular - Redirect to another component if conditions are not satisfied

Tags: angular

I have a component that's the first component I started in my project after login. I need to verify some value for loading it. I tried in this way:
In the ngOnit I call the account service, I cache the result into a property that i need to pass in the next service: "getCompanies" and after that I do a subscribe. Into the subscribe I need to do a control: If account has hasPrincipalRole setted to true and the result of getCompanies is an empty object I have to go on startup route, If not I must start getDashboard service. I tested it and it works but everytime happens that for 2-3 seconds I can see the dashboard component loaded before the redirect to "startup" route. How can avoid this situation? I have the same problem with canActivate in the routing, when I check if I'm authorized there are few seconds in which I see the component that I couldn't view. Which is the best solution?

```
    this.accountService.identity().pipe(
      switchMap(account => {
        this.account = account;
        return this.sidebarService.getCompanies(this.account.id.toString());
      }))
      .subscribe(res => {
         if (this.account.hasPrincipalRole && Object.keys(res).length === 0) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/startup');
        }
        else {
          this.getDashboard(this.account.id);
        }
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property/subject in your component

```
public isLoading = true;
```

In your HTML add a ngIf to your main div

```
<div *ngIf="!isLoading; else loading">
...
</div>
<div #loading>Loading</div>
```

In your subscribe you set the variable after the dashboard have loaded (I don't know what your getDashboard do so maybe it has to be put somewhere else)

```
 ...
 else {
      this.getDashboard(this.account.id);
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
```

Using an observable/subject instead of a variable might be easier to control in some cases